# Get count of div from html string (returned from API JSON)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I've created a live feed (like Facebook's) wherein if you scroll to the bottom of the div, it gets more feeds via ajax. Also, it keeps checking for new feeds at iteration of 5 secs and if new feeds are found, they're loaded at the top of the div. Now, every time new feed is found, I want to show it's count in notification. And btw, the feed data is returned in a json array in form `{'success':true,'data':'the-html-form-of-new-feeds'}`.

I want to count the number of feeds in `data` part for which I'm using `$(json.data).find('.one_feed').length` (`json` is the returned json array), but everytime I get 0 as count. What's wrong here, please?

Comment: Can you also post an example of the json response object?

Comment: it's in form: `{'success':true,'data':'<div class="one_feed">feed content</div><div class="one_feed"></div>'}`

Comment: to be exact, it's like this: `{"success":true,"data":"\n    <div class='one_feed' rel='2014-08-27 12:13:50' activity-type='like' activity-object='discussion'>\n        <a href='' class='user'>\n            <img src='/images\/avatar\/thumb_m_1344574536.jpg' alt='Administrator'>\n        <\/a>\n        <div>\n            <a href=''>Administrator<\/a> liked a<span class='action'> Parent talk<\/span>: <a class='link Parent talk' href=''>Parentune  Discussion<\/a> \n        <\/div>\n    <\/div>"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you `data` html code with another HTML element (for example, with `div`) and search in it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjbwyog7/).

```
$(function()
{
    var data = '<div class="one_feed">feed content</div><div class="one_feed"></div>';
    var wrap = $('<div>');
    wrap.html(data);
    alert(wrap.find('.one_feed').length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. I knew that there was something wrong because of that `\n` character being appended to the html, but I didn't know how to tackle that. Anyways, thanks :)

Comment: @Marcus you're welcome. Just to mention: it will work much faster, if instead of creating DOM structure from `data` string (like in your question and my answer) you will use simple JavaScript search (for example, `indexOf`) in string for another string, but code will be much more complicated (especially due to checking that found string is part of class), and in not critical situations this speeding up is not worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly accessing the `data` property of the json response. It can be accessed using `json['data']`
Try this:

```
$(json['data']).find('.one_feed').length;
```

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. `console.log(len)` still gives 0. Also, as I've already defined datatype for my `$.post` request as json, json.data do give me the html content. The proof is that it is being appended to the div!

Comment: @Marcus Can you post a fiddle recreating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that jquery is searching divs inside the string, and not the dom element

Try  yo apply your form in HTML using :

```
 $('#some_div_id').append(json.data);
 $('#some_div_id').find('.one_feed').length;
```

Ans the \n string doesnt work un HTML, use

Comment: I didn't try this approach but it seemed to me very unrealistic as why would I append the html to a dynamic div (adding it to dom) if I've to append it to some other div already! Anyways, thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
var response = {'success':true,'data':'<div class="one_feed">feed content</div><div class="one_feed"></div>'};
console.log($(response.data).length)
```

The above code solves your problem!!

Comment: That doesn't. That's what I was trying earlier. But seemingly, PHP was adding `\n` character in between divs so it was losing it's html structure.